# Passing mouse events from Jframe glass to menu bar?

Tags: java, swing

Based on previous stack questions I have written the following code to capture mouse input from the glass pane push it to a series of panels underneath.

```
 MouseMotionListener mml = new MouseMotionListener() {
  private void DispatchMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {

      Point glassPanePoint = e.getPoint();
      Container container = jf.getContentPane();
      Point containerPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(
              glass, glassPanePoint, container);
      if (containerPoint.y >= 0) {
          for (Component ml : mouseListeners) {
              Point componentPoint = SwingUtilities
                      .convertPoint( glass, glassPanePoint, ml);
              ml.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(ml, e.getID(), 
                      e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers(),
                      componentPoint.x, componentPoint.y,
                      e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger()));
          }
      }
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
      DispatchMouseEvent(me);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
      DispatchMouseEvent(me);
  }
};
glass.addMouseMotionListener(mml);
```

But all of the tutorials I can find say something like this when it comes to the menu bar.

```
if (containerPoint.y < 0) { //we're not in the content pane
        if (containerPoint.y + menuBar.getHeight() >= 0) { 
            //The mouse event is over the menu bar.
            //Could handle specially.
        } else { 
            //The mouse event is over non-system window 
            //decorations, such as the ones provided by
            //the Java look and feel.
            //Could handle specially.
        }
```

Could someone point me to somewhere so I can see how to handle that specifically? Thanks.

Comment: The `glassPane` covers the `JRootPane`, which contains the `JMenuBar` AND the `contentPane`, you should be determining, as best you can, which of the two components the mouse event is likely generated in.  Although, I'm sitting here scratching my head of why you'd even bother. The main reason for adding a `MouseListener` to a glass pane is so you can trap mouse events, if you want them to fall through, just remove the `MouseListener`

Comment: I have a series of graphs on top of each other (stacked vertically, not in the z-axis) and they should all be updating their dependent values in the display no matter where the y-value of the mouse (i.e if my mouse is on my line graph, my candle graph should still be updating.)

Comment: Okay, but why use a `glassPane` for that?  Why not just use a normal `JPanel` and add it to the `contentPane`?

Comment: I am making this up as I read tutorials so I probably misinterpreted, I will try to the content pane, thanks.